# Google Font does not import into React native app

Tags: react-native, google-font-api, google-fonts

I am trying to import a font from google fonts into my RN app. However, I came across an issue where it tells me that the font is unrecognizable. Here is what I did:

I downloaded the font and added into an assets folder:

```
/assests/fonts/
```

Set up my package.json like this:

```
"rnpm": {
"assets": [
"./assets/fonts/"
   ]
 }
```

Ran the following below in terminal:

```
react-native link
```

I also went into Info.plist file for ios and manually added the font since it didn't do so after linking:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Lacquer-Regular.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Finally, I have it labeled like this on my page in vscode.

```
fontFamily: "Lacquer-Regular"
```

Any idea as to what may have happened and how it can be fixed?

Comment: what version of RN are you using?

Comment: @Train react-native: 0.60.3

Comment: Not sure if this is your reason, but the folder name you've mentioned (/assests/fonts/) has an extra 's' in the name. This could also explain why npm link didn't just work right away?

Comment: @csb00 try my solution below Its working

Comment: @csb00 did you try my working solution posted below?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal yup - thank you! :-)

Comment: @csb00 then mark it as the correct answer or accepted answer by clicking the tick button next to the answer so that future users can be directly benefitted from it.

Answer (score 7):

For those who are using **react-native version > 0.60** , **`'rnpm' is deprecated`** and custom fonts will not work.

Now, in order to add custom font in react-native version > 0.60 you will have to :

1- Create a file named `react-native.config.js` in the root folder of your project.

2- add this in that new file

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/']
};
```

3- run `react-native link` command in the root project path.

**PS** Make sure you have the right path for the fonts folder before running `react-native link` command

Answer (score 1):

"./assets/fonts/" Does this path contain files? `Lacquer-Regular.ttf`

If you don't have a file, please add it and `link` it.

When you make a `link`, the following result should occur:
[image: link]

And if a link doesn't have a target, it can affect the project by doing all the links. Link directly to the path as possible.

```
react-native link ./assets/fonts
```